# add a column to allocate wishes according to the condition of the student and the remaining places

Tags: r

I want to create a new column (UE) by assigning for each student (id), according to their classification (order) one of their choices of teaching unit (u1 to u3) in the following order (C1, C2, C3) while checking for each assignment the number of place remaining in each teaching unit (u1=2 places max, u2= 2 places max, u3 = 3 places max).

```
    id<-c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16)
    C1<-c("u1","u2","u2","u2","u1","u1")
    C2<-c("u3","u3","u3","u3","u3","u2")
    C3<-c("u2","u1","u1","u1","u2","na")
    order<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

d = data.frame(id, C1, C2, C3, order)
```

The right answer is in the example file below.

```
id     C1 C2 C3 Ordre UE
1 11   u1 u3 u2     1 u1
2 12   u2 u3 u1     2 u2
3 13   u2 u3 u1     3 u2
4 14   u2 u3 u1     4 u3
5 15   u1 u3 u2     5 u1
6 16   u1 u2 na     6 without allocation
```

however, using my code

```
d$UE <- ifelse(d$C1== "u1" & length(d$C1[d$C1=="u1"])<=2, 'u1',
    ifelse(d$C1== "u2" & length(d$C1[d$C1=="u2"])<=2, 'u2',
    ifelse(d$C1== "u3" & length(d$C1[d$C1=="u3"])<=3, 'u3', 
           
    ifelse(d$C2== "u1" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u1"])<=2, 'u1',
    ifelse(d$C2== "u2" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u2"])<=2, 'u2',
    ifelse(d$C2== "u3" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u3"])<=3, 'u3',
    
    ifelse(d$C2== "u1" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u1"])<=2, 'u1',
    ifelse(d$C2== "u2" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u2"])<=2, 'u2',
    ifelse(d$C2== "u3" & length(d$C2[d$C2=="u3"])<=3, 'u3',              
           'without allocation')))))))))
```

I get

```
id C1 C2 C3 order                 UE
1 11 u1 u3 u2     1 without allocation
2 12 u2 u3 u1     2 without allocation
3 13 u2 u3 u1     3 without allocation
4 14 u2 u3 u1     4 without allocation
5 15 u1 u3 u2     5 without allocation
6 16 u1 u2 na     6                 u2
```

I thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could you please post your original data set?

Comment: I enclose the original data : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/44df3c8f42e120560c62ce6c91ffe4ed20210724073927/626d48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your maximum amount of places in a separate variable and than count the allocated places:

```r
# max places per unit
max_place <- c(u1 = 2, u2 = 2, u3 = 3)
# occupid places per unit
occ_place <- c(u1 = 0, u2 = 0, u3 = 0)

d$UE <- "without allocation"

# loop through your data.frame
for (i in seq_along(d)) {
  # loop over choices 
  for (j in c("C1", "C2", "C3")) {
    # check if there are places availble and allocate the unit
    if (occ_place[d[i,j]] < max_place[d[i, j]] & !is.na(d[i,j]) & d[i,j] != "na") {
      d$UE[i] <- d[i,j]
      occ_place[d[i,j]] <- occ_place[d[i,j]] + 1
      break
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```r
  id C1 C2 C3 order                 UE
1 11 u1 u3 u2     1                 u1
2 12 u2 u3 u1     2                 u2
3 13 u2 u3 u1     3                 u2
4 14 u2 u3 u1     4                 u3
5 15 u1 u3 u2     5                 u1
6 16 u1 u2 na     6 without allocation
```

Comment: `d` should now have a column `UE` filled with your desired output. `!is.na(d[i,j]) & d[i,j] != "na"` check, if the choice in scope is either a missing value (`is.na()`) or isn't one of the choices, but the string "na". Those values aren't handled like the other ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will apply your solution for 4 possible choices and 10 possible teaching units. occ_place <- c(u1 = 0, u2 = 0, u3 = 0) it's just for the initial place number ?

Comment: the initial `occ_place` is `0` for every unit.

Comment: when I apply the script on a file of 200 rows, the sorting does not work anymore. As if the seq_long function stops at the 7th line ?

Comment: I enclose the original data : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/44df3c8f42e120560c62ce6c91ffe4ed20210724073927/626d48

Comment: max_place <- c(u1 = 30, u2 = 20, u3 = 30, u4 = 30, u5 = 30, u6 = 30, u7 = 20, u8 = 30, u9 = 40) 
occ_place <- c(u1 = 2, u2 = 0, u3 = 5, u4 = 0, u5 = 0, u6 = 0, u7 = 0, u8 = 14, u9 = 0)
d$UE <- "without allocation"
for (i in seq_along(d)) {
  # loop over choices 
  for (j in c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")) {
    # check if there are places availble and allocate the unit
    if (occ_place[d[i,j]] < max_place[d[i, j]] & !is.na(d[i,j]) & d[i,j] != "na") {
      d$UE[i] <- d[i,j]
      occ_place[d[i,j]] <- occ_place[d[i,j]] + 1
      break
    }
  }
}